# How can $3^{-n}= 0$ be true for any $n$?

Tags: general-topology

There is an answer that has 7 up votes (so it is probably right) that says,

> [There are no segments of positive length left (this may be seen by,
>   for instance, looking at the lengths of the segments at each
>   iteration; after the $n$th iteration, the segments have length
>   $3^{-n}$).](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2221069/307169)

My understanding is that  for every $n \in \mathbb N : 3^{-n} \not= 0$

There may be some rule that allows us to say that $ 3^{-n} = 0$ under some condition, but it is not at all obvious to someone (like me) who has not studied math. After all topology is a very strange branch of mathematics.

Can someone explain the thinking behind this answer?

Comment: That statement applies in the limit as $n\to \infty$.  You are absolutely correct that $3^{-n}\neq0$ for any finite $n$

Comment: Suppose there would be an open interval $(a,b)$ inside the Cantor set. As $b-a>0$, for some value of $n$, $0<3^{-n} < b-a$. So already at that stage $(a,b)$ cannot be contained in one part of that stage, so some part of it will not be in $C$ at all.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, Would it be correct to say that for every interval $(a,b) \in \mathbb C : a=b$ thus the length is zero?

Comment: If the length is positive it cannot be contained in the Cantor set

Answer (score 3):

The Cantor set is the intersection of all its iterations.  What the author is trying to say is: the Cantor set contains no interval.  Why not?  Let $I$ be an interval of length $L>0$.  Then there is some $n$ such that $3^{-n}<L$.  Therefore, $I$ cannot be contained in the $n$-th iteration towards the Cantor set, and therefore cannot be contained in the Cantor set itself.

You are correct that $3^{-n}\neq 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that when constructing the Cantor set, at each step the segments have size $3^{-n}$, so at each step there are intervals of positive length. But the construction goes through all the natural numbers, so after we exhausted all the natural numbers, we end up with a set that contains no (nontrivial) intervals.

Answer (score 1):

It's a limit process.  If you aren't familiar with the concept of limits, the Cantor set is not a good introduction to it, in my opinion.

It's true that $3^{-n} \ne 0$ for any $n \in \Bbb N$ (and really for any $n \in \Bbb R$).

However, the *limit* as $n \to +\infty$ of $3^{-n}$ *is* zero.  We denote this by writing $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to +\infty} 3^{-n} = 0$.

In general, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to c} f(n)$ describes what $f(n)$ looks like or how $f(n)$ "behaves" as $n$ gets extremely close to $c$.  Or, in the case that $c$ is $+\infty$, it describes what $f(n)$ looks like or how $f(n)$ "behaves" as $n$ gets extremely huge, i.e., as we send $n$ off in the direction of $+\infty$ and never let it stop.

And in this case, we can see that as $n$ gets larger and larger, the value of $3^{-n}$ always remains positive but continues to decrease, getting smaller and smaller.  As $n$ gets infinitely larger, $3^{-n}$ gets infinitely closer to zero.  So its *limit* is zero, but $3^{-n}$ never takes on the *value* zero for any $n$.  But limits don't care about actual function values, only what the function *looks* like it's going to do.